# inline block not working Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

For some reason, I cannot get the elements in column 2 to align as inline-block items, either with the bootstrap HTML `d-inline-block` or with my own CSS inline-block applied.  It doesn't seem to matter whether my stylesheet named MainPage.css has priority over bootstrap or not.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MainPage.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- <h1>Hello, world!</h1> -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row vh">
        <div class="col-md-2 pt-3">

            <ul id="socialmedia">
                <li><a class="pl-2" id="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="facebook16.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a class="pl-2" id="twitter" href="https://www.twitter.com/"><img src="twitter16.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a class="pl-2" id="instagram" href="https://www.twitter.com/"><img src="instagram16.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a class="pl-2" id="youtube" href="https://www.twitter.com/"><img src="youtube16.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a class="pl-2" id="spotify" href="https://www.twitter.com/"><img src="spotify16.png"/></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-6 pt-4">

            <ul id="leftbanner">
                <li><a class="" id="News" href="https://www.google.com/">News</a></li>
                <li><a class="pl-2" id="Photos" href="https://www.google.com/">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a class="pl-2" id="Tour" href="https://www.google.com/">Tour</a></li>
                <li><a class="pl-2" id="Games" href="https://www.google.com/">Games</a></li>
            </ul>

            <p id="centerpage">BlackBird | Blue Bird</p>


            <ul id="rightbanner">
                <li><a class="" id="News" href="https://www.google.com/">News</a></li>
                <li><a class=" pl-2" id="Photos" href="https://www.google.com/">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a class=" pl-2" id="Tour" href="https://www.google.com/">Tour</a></li>
                <li><a class=" pl-2" id="Games" href="https://www.google.com/">Games</a></li>
            </ul>


        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript  color #4f4f52 -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url(BG1.jpg);
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
/*    background-size: 100% 100%; */
background-size: cover;
margin: 0%;
padding: 0%;
}


#socialmedia li  {

list-style-type: none;
display: inline;

}

#leftbanner li {

list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;

}


#rightbanner li {

list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;

}

#centerpage{

display: inline-block;

}
.container-fluid{

padding:0;
margin:0;
}

.vh div{
height: 7vh;
background: #f9f9fa;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `d-inline-block` class to the `li` items, it works as expected. (see code snippet below).

However, you might rather want to use the Bootstrap 4 `nav` classes for this job because they were designed precisely for that and will make your life easier than working with `d-inline-block` classes in this case.

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/

Here's a working code snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row vh">
        <div class="col-md-2 pt-3">

            <ul id ="socialmedia" class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a class="pl-2" id ="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="https://placehold.it/24"/></a></li>
                <li><a class="pl-2" id ="twitter" href="https://www.twitter.com/"><img src="https://placehold.it/24"/></a></li>
                <li><a class="pl-2" id ="instagram" href="https://www.twitter.com/"><img src="https://placehold.it/24"/></a></li>
                <li><a class="pl-2" id ="youtube" href="https://www.twitter.com/"><img src="https://placehold.it/24"/></a></li>
                <li><a class="pl-2" id ="spotify" href="https://www.twitter.com/"><img src="https://placehold.it/24"/></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 pt-4">

            <ul id ="leftbanner" class="list-unstyled">
                <li class="d-inline-block"><a class="" id ="News" href="https://www.google.com/">News</a></li>
                <li class="d-inline-block"><a class="pl-2" id ="Photos" href="https://www.google.com/">Photos</a></li>
                <li class="d-inline-block"><a class="pl-2" id ="Tour" href="https://www.google.com/">Tour</a></li>
                <li class="d-inline-block"><a class="pl-2" id ="Games" href="https://www.google.com/">Games</a></li>
            </ul>

            <p id ="centerpage">BlackBird | Blue Bird</p>

            <ul id ="rightbanner" class="list-unstyled">
                <li class="d-inline-block"><a class="" id ="News" href="https://www.google.com/">News</a></li>
                <li class="d-inline-block"><a class=" pl-2" id ="Photos" href="https://www.google.com/">Photos</a></li>
                <li class="d-inline-block"><a class=" pl-2" id ="Tour" href="https://www.google.com/">Tour</a></li>
                <li class="d-inline-block"><a class=" pl-2" id ="Games" href="https://www.google.com/">Games</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I might try nav, however i tried the above code with no success.  i understand the commands and doc but it doesn't seem to work when i use that particular bootstrap class, it doesn't even show up autofinish tab

Comment: If you copy and paste my code, it'll work with 100% success rate.

Comment: from the code above: the two ul 's and p are not inline, merely the elements in the list.  How would i achieve the three positioned adjacent to one another in the middle column.  Thank you!

Comment: That seems to be a new question. Since SO rules don't allow us to ask/answer multiple questions in one, I suggest you click the checkmark next to my answer here to accept it (assuming I answered this question which I think I did) and then post a new question regarding that other issue. I'll gladly answer that as well.

Comment: adding d-inline-block worked(for ul class), my css was in fact over riding some code. Apologies, thank you for your prompt answer!